# Firebird insert...returning asp.net

Tags: asp.net, sql, firebird

I'm using Firebird 2.5 and asp.net (4.5).

I'm trying to find out how to use insert ... returning, or some equivalent.

Using fbDataReader, it executes the insert OK, but I can't find anyway of accessing a returned value. Using fbDataReader.GetName(0) seems to work ok, returning the variable name in the "returning" clause. This even applies to a max() in a subselect:
..... returning (select max(userid) as newid from users)
returns the text "newid".
I can't find where, or whether, the value is available.

Using a fbDataAdaptor to fill a DataTable, the insert works OK, but data table seems empty.

Does anyone know whether this is possible, and if so, how it's done?

Thanks

EDIT
Code supplied :

```
strConn = .... 
dbConn = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbConnection(strConn)
dbConn.Open()

MySQL = "insert into  users (Firstname, Lastname) VALUES (@fname,@lname) returning userid"
FbC = New FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbCommand(MySQL, dbConn)
FbC.Parameters.Add("fname", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Text).Value = "Pete"
FbC.Parameters.Add("lname", FirebirdSql.Data.FirebirdClient.FbDbType.Text).Value = "Davis"

FbDataReader = FbC.ExecuteReader()
FbDataReader.Read()
TextBox1.Text = FbDataReader.GetName(0)
'TextBox1.Text  = str(FbDataReader.GetInt64())
'TextBox1.Text = FbDataReader.GetString(0)
TextBox1.Text = FbDataReader.GetValue(0)
```

Comment: I removed my original answer Steve, hopefully someone will spot the unanswered question and step in. I tried adding extra info but the edit hasn't shown up :(

Answer (score 0):

According to [this thread](http://firebird.1100200.n4.nabble.com/RETURNING-clause-and-Firebird-NET-Provider-td3039724.html) `INSERT ... RETURNING ...` behaves like output parameters for the Firebird .NET provider. So you will need to add an output parameter.

So something like the code below should work:

```
FbParameter outParam = new FbParam("userid", FbDbType.Integer) 
   {
      Direction = ParameterDirection.Output
   };
FbC.Parameters.Add(outParam);
FbC.ExecuteNonQuery();
int? userId = outParam.Value as int?;
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, I didn't get this to work - same problem as before. Writing it as a stored procedure worked fine, so that's how I finished up.