# Why the ExecuteNonQuery catch exception {"validation error for column \"ORGTABLE\".\"FIKEYID\", value \"* null *\""}

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

Why the ExecuteNonQuery catch exception {"validation error for column \"ORGTABLE\".\"FIKEYID\", value \"*** null ***\""}

```
string stValuesPlaceHolder = "@p0";
for (int iii = 1; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++)
    stValuesPlaceHolder += ", @p" + (iii).ToString();

FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO " + stTableName + "(" + stFieldNamesNoKeyId + ") VALUES ( " + stValuesPlaceHolder + " )", fbConn, fbTransaction);

for (int iii = 0; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++) {
    string stPlaceHolder = "@p" + (iii).ToString();
    string stValue = liststFieldValuesNoKeyId[iii];
    fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(stPlaceHolder, stValue);
}

fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
fbTransaction.Commit();
```

The stTableName is OrgTable.

The fields names are:

```
fstPriority, fstInfo, fstDateCreated, fstDateModified, fiKeyID.
```

The field definitions are:

```
fstPriority VARCHAR(30), fstInfo VARCHAR(100), fstDateCreated VARCHAR(30), fstDateModified VARCHAR(30), fiKeyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

---

In this section of the code:

```
stFieldNamesNoKeyId = "fstPriority, fstInfo, fstDateCreated, fstDateModified".

stValuesPlaceHolder = "@p0, @p1, @p2, @p3"
```

Four 
    fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue:

```
stPlaceHolder = "@p0" ... stValue = "1st value";

stPlaceHolder = "@p1" ... stValue = "2nd value";

stPlaceHolder = "@p2" ... stValue = "3rd value";

stPlaceHolder = "@p3" ... stValue = "4th value";
```

I did not add a value for fiKeyID as it as the PRIMARY KEY.

Comment: What is the DDL of the table, and which Firebird version are you using. Do you have a trigger to generate the ID for you? Otherwise not including a value for the primary key will lead to `null` being assigned, which is not allowed, so the exception is correct and expected in that case. BTW: I assume you mean "Why the ExecuteNonQuery **throws** exception".

Comment: Can you do an insert with SQL only?

If not, I suspect that the problem is the key field - in SQL server it would normally be set to identity and have a seed and increment value of 1

Comment: Firebird ADO.NET  ... FirebirdClient.5.8.0 ----- The above has been used successfully for writing to Access.accdb and SQLite.  For Access.accdb, the primary key was defined by Access.accdb designer ... for SQLite the primary key was defined as INTEGER PRIMARY KEY. ----- What is the trigger to generate the ID?

Comment: Excel/Access (Microsoft Jet) is not an SQL database, though there is some bridge to use parts of SQL to fetch data from it. SQLite has non-standard behavior that every row has a dedicated ROWID column no matter if you want it or not - https://www.sqlite.org/autoinc.html - adn ur primary key is silently dropped and short-curcuited for it. But i wonder if there would be possibility to backup/restore SQLite DB or to connect SQLite DB for several different computers simultaneously, would that ROWID column be still feasible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Definitions:

```
public const string stMAIN_TABLE_NAME = " OrgTable ";
public const string stDELETED_TABLE_NAME = "  BackupTable ";

public const string stFIELD_DEFINITIONS = " fstPriority VARCHAR(30)" + 
                                          ", fstInfo VARCHAR(100)" +
                                          ", fstDateCreated VARCHAR(30)" +
                                          ", fstDateModified VARCHAR(30)" +
                                          ", fiKeyID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ";

public const string stFIELD_NAMES_NO_KEY_ID = " fstPriority" + 
                                              ", fstInfo" + 
                                              ", fstDateCreated" + 
                                              ", fstDateModified ";

public const string stFIELD_NAMES_KEY_ID = " fiKeyID ";

public const string stFIELD_NAMES = stFIELD_NAMES_NO_KEY_ID + ", " + stFIELD_NAMES_KEY_ID;
```

Code:

```
//------------------------------
static private bool boCreateDatabaseTables(string stPathFilename, 
                                           string stUserID, 
                                           string stPassword, 
                                           List<string> liststTableNames, 
                                           List<string> liststFieldDefinitions) 
{
  bool boErrorFlag = false;
  int iTablesCount = liststTableNames.Count();
  string stOpenConn = new FbConnectionStringBuilder {
    Database = stPathFilename,
    UserID = stUserID,
    Password = stPassword,
    ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
    ClientLibrary = stCLIENT_LIBRARY
    }.ToString();
  using (FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn)) {
    try {
      fbConn.Open();

      FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
      for (int ii = 0; ii < iTablesCount; ii++) {
        string stSql = "CREATE TABLE " + liststTableNames[ii] + "( " + liststFieldDefinitions[ii] + ")";
        FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stSql, fbConn, fbTransaction);
        fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      }
      fbTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      boErrorFlag = true;
      MessageBox.Show("catch ... GlobalsFirebird ... boCreateDatabaseTables ... " + ex.Message);
    }
}
return boErrorFlag;
}//boCreateDatabaseTables
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
static public bool boAddRow(string stPathFilename,
                            string stUserID,
                            string stPassword,
                            string stTableName,
                            string stFieldNamesNoKeyId,
                            string stFieldNamesKeyId,
                            List<string> liststFieldValuesNoKeyId) 
{
  bool boErrorFlag = false;
  string stOpenConn = new FbConnectionStringBuilder {
    Database = stPathFilename,
    UserID = stUserID,
    Password = stPassword,
    ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
    ClientLibrary = stCLIENT_LIBRARY
  }.ToString();

  using(FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn)) {
    fbConn.Open();
    try {
      string stValuesPlaceHolder = "@p0";
      for (int iii = 1; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++)
        stValuesPlaceHolder += ", @p" + (iii).ToString();
      FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
      string stCmd = "INSERT INTO " + stTableName + "(" + stFieldNamesNoKeyId + ") VALUES ( " + stValuesPlaceHolder + " ) RETURNING  " + stFieldNamesKeyId;
      FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stCmd, fbConn, fbTransaction);

      for (int iii = 0; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++) {
        string stPlaceHolder = "@p" + (iii).ToString();
        string stValue = liststFieldValuesNoKeyId[iii];
        fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(stPlaceHolder, stValue);
      }
      fbCmd.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter() { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output });
      fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
      fbTransaction.Commit();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
      boErrorFlag = true;
      MessageBox.Show("catch ... GlobalsFirebird ... boAddRow ... " + ex.Message);
    }
  }
  return boErrorFlag;
}//boAddRow
//------------------------------
```

Comment: The credit for the answer belongs to Mark Rotteveel ... see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43020306/how-do-insert-into-firebird-with-autoincrement-for-the-primary-key.

Answer (score 1):

> I did not add a value for fiKeyID as it as the PRIMARY KEY.

So you try to insert a NULL primary key. This is not allowed.

http://www.firebirdsql.org/manual/nullguide-keys.html

> NULLs are never allowed in primary keys. A column can only be (part of) a PK if it has been defined as NOT NULL, either in the column definition or in a domain definition.

Then, you might want to ask server for auto-generating IDs. There are few ways of doing it.

Firebird 3 comes with auto-inc column type, for example. *Which is a syntactic sugar over tools that were explicitly used by database developer before.*

Firebird 2 and prior versions used GENERATORS (aka SQL SEQUENCE) to achieve it.

You have to make a BEFORE-INSERT (or BEFORE-INSERT-OR-UPDATE) trigger on the table, that would fill the ID field from the generator, if the ID field was NULL.  http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/

```
CREATE GENERATOR gen_t1_id;
SET GENERATOR gen_t1_id TO 0;
set term !! ;
 CREATE TRIGGER T1_BI FOR T1
 ACTIVE BEFORE INSERT POSITION 0
 AS
 BEGIN
 if (NEW.ID is NULL) then NEW.ID = GEN_ID(GEN_T1_ID, 1);
 END!!
set term ; !!
```

There it boils down to your SQL access library.
Because typically after you inserted the row - you have to know its ID.

If you do not care about that ID of newborn row, you may skip the rest.

But if you want to both insert the row and know its ID then it boils down to another choice.

Low-tech SQL-only libraries would force you to take a doubletrip:

- `SELECT GEN_ID(GEN_T1_ID, 1) FROM RDB$DATABASE` or `SELECT NEXT VALUE FOR GEN_T1_ID FROM RDB$DATABASE` would reserve you a free token, then you would explicitly assign your ID PK-column to that value and insert it together with data columns, bypassing the trigger.
- Or with advanced SQL libraries you may ask Firebird to auto-calculate value and report it to you: `INSERT INTO tablename(data1,data2,dataq3) VALUES (1,2,3) RETURNING id`. See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Insert_(SQL)#Retrieving_the_key

Whether you need to learn the inserted ID or not, and whether your SQL library supports INSERT-RETURNING command or not - it is up to you to decide.

However when I do Google search ( it is www.google.com ) it comes with many links about `C# Firebird Insert Returniung` for many different C# SQL libraries, and again only you can tell which one you use. For few examples from different libs:

- http://www.ibprovider.com/eng/documentation/firebird_21_adonet.html
- http://www.sql.ru/forum/actualutils.aspx?action=gotomsg&tid=720869&msg=8075816
- [Retrieve last id from Firebird db table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20271814/)
- [Firebird insert...returning asp.net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15681172/)
- https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/e7099cfb-7809-460a-aae9-79a2bd703454/how-i-can-return-the-id-after-insert-a-record-into-a-database-firebird-25-with-linq?forum=adodotnetentityframework

et cetera

Comment: I see at http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/ --- INSERT INTO t1(field1) VALUES('my stuff') RETURNING id; --- I can add RETURNING id, ---     FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand("INSERT ... RETURNING (" + id + ")", fbConn, fbTransaction); --- but am uncertain what should be used for the fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue ---  Do I add stPlaceHolder = "@p5" ... stValue = "".

Comment: @ttom i know next to nothing about C#, guess you have to contact DotNetProvider forum or search for snippets of C# code using insert-returning.  I tell you how it is normally done in Firebird, but I don't know how good or bad C# FB libraries are.

Comment: also try to learn how you in C# call such statements as `EXECUTE BLOCK` or calling a `Stored Procedure`. Cause on FB API level `INSERT-RETURNING` is classified as SP-call type of statement. Maybe that is how they are exposed on DotNetProvider API too. Maybe not

Comment: Also guess I was a bit wrong and the RETURNING comes without parenthesis. http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=returning http://firebirdsql.su/doku.php?id=update_or_insert fixing my answer now