# How do INSERT INTO Firebird, with autoincrement for the primary key?

Tags: c#, ado.net, firebird, firebird-embedded

How do INSERT INTO Firebird, with autoincrement for the primary key?

For the table fields I have:

```
fstPriority VARCHAR(30), fstInfo VARCHAR(100), fstDateCreated VARCHAR(30), fstDateModified VARCHAR(30), fiKeyID INTEGER PRIMARY KEY
```

For the INSERT INTO I have:

```
FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn))
fbConn.Open();
...
FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand("INSERT INTO " + stTableName + "(" + stFieldNames + ") VALUES ( @p0, @p1, @p2, @p3, @p4 ) RETURNING fiKeyID ", fbConn, fbTransaction);
```

but am uncertain what should be used for the
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue

```
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p0", "1st value");
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p1", "2nd value");
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p2", "3rd value");
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p3", "4th value");
```

Then what? For fiKeyID, do I add

```
fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@p4", "");
```

Also, I see at http://www.firebirdfaq.org/faq29/ creating an autoincrement column, but am uncertain how to do this in C# ... Firebird ADO.NET ... FirebirdClient.5.8.0 ... Visual Studio 2013.

```
CREATE GENERATOR ...;
SET GENERATOR ...;

set term !! ;
CREATE TRIGGER ...
```

are not recognized by the Visual Studio compiler.

Comment: If you have a column that uses a sequence/generator, you do not specify a value for that column, it will automatically assign the next value in the sequence. If you are performing any kind of migration, and you need to specify values for auto-incremented fields, you will need to disable the sequence/generator first, then when you are done you will need to update the sequence to the new ending value, and re-enable it.

Comment: Are you defining the structure of your tables programmatically?

Comment: Yes, tables are created programmatically ---  FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction() --- for (int ii = 0; ii < iTablesCount; ii++) {string stSql = "CREATE TABLE " + liststTableNames[ii] + "( " + liststFieldDefinitions[ii] + ")" --- FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stSql, fbConn, fbTransaction); --- fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();} fbTransaction.Commit();

Comment: when I drafted my on-the-go statement generator, the columns were having flags, so the record-like object has methods like `GetIDColumnsArray` and `GetDataColumnsArray` ( a bit more complex actually, cause they could overlap,  but that does not matter ). So I believe you have to have a similar structures, describing your tables, so your query building would look like that: `fbCmd = new FbCommand( tbl.InsertPrologue() + " ("+ tbl.getDataColumns().JoinString() + ") values (" + tbl.getDataColumns(),Substitutes().JoinString() + ") returning " + tbl.getIDColumns().JoinString();

Comment: That way you would centralize structure declarations, and make few reusable routines to build SQL statements. And would not mistakingly assign value for columns from ID-cortege.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

An important thing is that `SET TERM` is **not** part of the Firebird statement syntax, instead it is a client-side feature to set the statement terminator in query tools like ISQL. This terminator is necessary to know when a statement is complete and can be sent to the server. By default these tools do that on a semi-colon (`;`), but that doesn't work with PSQL (stored procedures, triggers), because PSQL code uses the semi-colon as well. To address this, these tools have `SET TERM` to switch this terminator.

Using the Firebird ADO.net provider however, you need to execute statements one at a time, so a statement terminator is irrelevant.

To be able to generate a primary key you can use the following solutions:

1. Firebird 3 has an identity type column, so you don't need to create a sequence and trigger yourself:

   ```sql
   create table withgeneratedid(
       id integer generated by default as identity primary key, 
       column2 varchar(100)
   )
   ```
2. For Firebird 2.5 and earlier you will need to create a sequence and trigger:

   ```sql
   create table withgeneratedid(
       id integer primary key,
       column2 varchar(100)
   );

   create sequence seq_withgeneratedid;

   set term #;
   create trigger withgeneratedid_bi before insert on withgeneratedid
   as
   begin
       if (new.id is null) then new.id = next value for seq_withgeneratedid;
   end#
   set term ;#
   ```

When you insert values into a table and want to have a generated key, you should **not** include the id column in the column-list. Including the id column allows you to override the key value, but that might lead to future inserts generating a duplicate key!. If you do include the id column, then no key will be generated in the Firebird 3 example, in the Firebird 2.5 example a key will be generated if the value of the column is `null`, otherwise it will take the provided value.

In ADO.net you'd normally need to execute the statements individually (and not use `set term`). Alternatively, you could use `FbScript` to parse a DDL script and execute the parse statements. Note that `FbScript` does support (and even requires) `set term`.

To execute this with the Firebird ADO.net provider, you can do something like the example below. I have included three alternatives for creating the table `Firebird3`, `Firebird2_5`, and `FbScriptFB2_5` (which is the same as `Firebird2_5` but uses `FbScript`). It also show how to retrieve the generated key:

```
namespace FbGeneratedKeys
{
    class Program
    {
        private static SolutionType solutionType = SolutionType.FbScriptFB2_5;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            var connectionString = new FbConnectionStringBuilder
            {
                Database = @"D:\temp\generatedkey.fdb",
                ServerType = FbServerType.Default,
                UserID = "SYSDBA",
                Password = "masterkey",
            }.ToString();
            FbConnection.CreateDatabase(connectionString, pageSize: 8192, overwrite : true);

            using (FbConnection connection = new FbConnection(connectionString))
            using (FbCommand cmd = new FbCommand())
            {
                connection.Open();

                cmd.Connection = connection;
                switch (solutionType) {
                    case SolutionType.Firebird3:
                        Firebird3Example(cmd);
                        break;
                    case SolutionType.Firebird2_5:
                        Firebird2_5Example(cmd);
                        break;
                    case SolutionType.FbScriptFB2_5:
                        FbScriptFB2_5Example(cmd);
                        break;
                }

                cmd.CommandText = @"insert into withgeneratedid(column2) values (@column2) returning id";
                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@column2", "some value");
                cmd.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter() { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output });
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

                Console.WriteLine("Id:" + cmd.Parameters[1].Value);
                Console.ReadLine();
            }
        }

        private static void Firebird3Example(FbCommand cmd)
        {
            // Firebird 3 identity column
            cmd.CommandText = @"create table withgeneratedid(
    id integer generated by default as identity primary key, 
    column2 varchar(100)
)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private static void Firebird2_5Example(FbCommand cmd)
        {
            // Firebird 2.5 and earlier normal primary key with trigger to generate key
            // Table
            cmd.CommandText = @"create table withgeneratedid(
    id integer primary key,
    column2 varchar(100)
)";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Sequence
            cmd.CommandText = "create sequence seq_withgeneratedid";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

            // Trigger
            cmd.CommandText = @"create trigger withgeneratedid_bi before insert on withgeneratedid
as
begin
    if (new.id is null) then new.id = next value for seq_withgeneratedid;
end";
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }

        private static void FbScriptFB2_5Example(FbCommand cmd)
        {
            string script = @"
create table withgeneratedid(
    id integer primary key,
    column2 varchar(100)
);

create sequence seq_withgeneratedid;

set term #;
create trigger withgeneratedid_bi before insert on withgeneratedid
as
begin
    if (new.id is null) then new.id = next value for seq_withgeneratedid;
end#
set term ;#
";
            FbScript fbScript = new FbScript(script);
            fbScript.Parse();
            FbBatchExecution exec = new FbBatchExecution(cmd.Connection);
            exec.AppendSqlStatements(fbScript);
            exec.Execute();
        }
    }

    enum SolutionType
    {
        Firebird3,
        Firebird2_5,
        FbScriptFB2_5
    }
}
```

Comment: Mark Rotteveel, How do I make your answer correct, and my answer correct (which has more details)?

Comment: Thanks Mark!  I'm just trying to help others ... not concerned about points.

Answer (score 0):

Definitions:

```
public const string stMAIN_TABLE_NAME = " OrgTable ";
public const string stDELETED_TABLE_NAME = "  BackupTable ";

public const string stFIELD_DEFINITIONS = " fstPriority VARCHAR(30)" + 
                                          ", fstInfo VARCHAR(100)" +
                                          ", fstDateCreated VARCHAR(30)" +
                                          ", fstDateModified VARCHAR(30)" +
                                          ", fiKeyID INTEGER GENERATED BY DEFAULT AS IDENTITY PRIMARY KEY ";
public const string stFIELD_NAMES = " fstPriority" + 
                                    ", fstInfo" + 
                                    ", fstDateCreated" + 
                                    ", fstDateModified" + 
                                    ", fiKeyID ";
public const string stFIELD_NAMES_NO_KEY_ID = " fstPriority" + 
                                              ", fstInfo" + 
                                              ", fstDateCreated" + 
                                              ", fstDateModified ";
```

Code:

```
//------------------------------
static private bool boCreateDatabaseTables(string stPathFilename, 
                                           string stUserID, 
                                           string stPassword, 
                                           List<string> liststTableNames, 
                                           List<string> liststFieldDefinitions) 
{
    bool boErrorFlag = false;
    int iTablesCount = liststTableNames.Count();
    string stOpenConn = new FbConnectionStringBuilder {
        Database = stPathFilename,
        UserID = stUserID,
        Password = stPassword,
        ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
        ClientLibrary = stCLIENT_LIBRARY
    }.ToString();
    using (FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn)) {
        try {
            fbConn.Open();

            FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
            for (int ii = 0; ii < iTablesCount; ii++) {
                string stSql = "CREATE TABLE " + liststTableNames[ii] + "( " + liststFieldDefinitions[ii] + ")";
                FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stSql, fbConn, fbTransaction);
                fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }
            fbTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            boErrorFlag = true;
            MessageBox.Show("catch ... GlobalsFirebird ... boCreateDatabaseTables ... " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return boErrorFlag;
}//boCreateDatabaseTables
//------------------------------
//------------------------------
static public bool boAddRow(string stPathFilename,
                            string stUserID,
                            string stPassword,
                            string stTableName,
                            string stFieldNamesNoKeyId,
                            List<string> liststFieldValuesNoKeyId) 
{
    bool boErrorFlag = false;
    string stOpenConn = new FbConnectionStringBuilder {
        Database = stPathFilename,
        UserID = stUserID,
        Password = stPassword,
        ServerType = FbServerType.Embedded,
        ClientLibrary = stCLIENT_LIBRARY
    }.ToString();

    using(FbConnection fbConn = new FbConnection(stOpenConn)) {
        fbConn.Open();
        try {
            string stValuesPlaceHolder = "@p0";
            for (int iii = 1; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++)
                stValuesPlaceHolder += ", @p" + (iii).ToString();
            FbTransaction fbTransaction = fbConn.BeginTransaction();
            string stCmd = "INSERT INTO " + stTableName + "(" + stFieldNamesNoKeyId + ") VALUES ( " + stValuesPlaceHolder + " ) RETURNING  fiKeyID ";
            FbCommand fbCmd = new FbCommand(stCmd, fbConn, fbTransaction);

            for (int iii = 0; iii < liststFieldValuesNoKeyId.Count; iii++) {
                string stPlaceHolder = "@p" + (iii).ToString();
                string stValue = liststFieldValuesNoKeyId[iii];
                fbCmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(stPlaceHolder, stValue);
            }
            fbCmd.Parameters.Add(new FbParameter() { Direction = System.Data.ParameterDirection.Output });
            fbCmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
            fbTransaction.Commit();
        }
        catch (Exception ex) {
            boErrorFlag = true;
            MessageBox.Show("catch ... GlobalsFirebird ... boAddRow ... " + ex.Message);
        }
    }
    return boErrorFlag;
}//boAddRow
//------------------------------
```